# JXTable Highlighter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, jxtable

I would like to highlight data in a JXTable based on the previous data in the table.  The data exists in "blocks" but the number of rows in each block of data varies based on a variety of factors; what I would like to do is alternately highlight each block of data if one element/column in the block (that is consistent throughout the block) is different enough from the previous block of data.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like "blocked striping" with variable block length: basically, you'll need a custom HighlightPredicate which detects the block boundaries. [Recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132400/jtable-row-hightlighter-based-on-value-from-tablecell) we came up with some logic which checks all values before and such keeps track of "oddness".