# how to change background color of individual cell in JTable in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I search in the table, when i find a match i want to change a bg color of that cell.
I did as below but still can't fix it? Can any body help to fix this problem?

```
public class SearchTable extends JTable {
JTable table;
JTextField textField;

public SearchTable(JTable table, JTextField textField) {
    this.table = table;
    this.textField = textField;

    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            search();
        }
    });

    textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            search();
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            search();
        }
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            search();
        }
    });
}

private void search() {
    String target = textField.getText();
    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            String next = (String) table.getValueAt(row, col);
            if (next.equals(target)) {
                changeBackgroundColor(row, col);
                return;
            }
        }
    table.repaint();
}

private void changeBackgroundColor(int row, int col) {
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    boolean toggle = false;
    boolean extend = false;
    table.changeSelection(row, col, toggle, extend);
    //first atempt sets bg color for all cells, it is not OK
    //table.setSelectionBackground(Color.green);

    //second atempt getting no result
    table.getCellEditor(row,col).getTableCellEditorComponent(table,table.getValueAt(row,col),true,row,col).setForeground(Color.red);

    //3th atempt getting no result
    //Component c = table.getCellRenderer(row, col).getTableCellRendererComponent(table, table.getValueAt(row, col), true, true, row, col);
    //c.setForeground(Color.red);

    //4th atempt getting no result
    //DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getCellRenderer(row, col).getTableCellRendererComponent(table, table.getValueAt(row, col), true, true, row, col).;
      //renderer.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
}

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XxxCellRenderer`, better and easiest is to use `prepareRenderer()`

for correct code you have to override or test inside if-else follows patameters

- isSelected
- hasFocus
- column
- row

Please to check [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:714968%20%5Bjava%5D%20prepareRenderer&submit=search) and one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132400/jtable-row-hightlighter-based-on-value-from-tablecell) about similair issue, there are two simple ways, sorry I‘m in FRI trafic, brrrrr

Comment: Concentrate on your driving.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson eeerrrghhtt finally I'm at home :-), terrible to wrote something in cellphone

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cell renderer to the column first -

```
col.setCellRenderer( new TableCellRenderer() {
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column ) 
                {
                    Component cell = centerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent( table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column );
    cell.setForeground(Color.green);
}
});
```

Comment: I think overriding `prepareRenderer()` may be easier for a single cell, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10755774/230513).